# scala class names in configuration map

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a web application built on play framework.

One of my endpoints provides response composed of output of different classes. The consumer can choose which pieces of output he wants to have in the response:
`GET /model/:modelId?fields=length,width,age`.
Accordingly, I have `LengthProvider`, `WidthProvider`.
Now, I want to have a configuration map in the controller, like

```
val providers = Map(
    "length" -> LengthProvider,
    "width"  -> WidthProvider
)
```

to be able to filter consumer's input by this map and apply all the providers, like

```
fields.collect {
    case field if providers.contains(field) => providers(field)(db).get(modelId)
  }
```

The problem arises when I try to build corresponding classes.
I have an abstract `FieldProvider`:

```
abstract class FieldProvider(db: DB) {
  def get(modelId: Long): Future[Seq[Writes]]
}
```

And corresponding implementations (`LengthProvider`, `WidthProvider`). Now, to make the configuration Map compile, I need to define companion objects for the classes I want to reference (e.g. I need `LengthProvider` object). And then, when I use the value of the Map (class name), I cannot initialize the class instance like I do that normally, I only have access to the `apply` method defined in companion object. But the problem is that this is not part of the abstract class I define, so the compiler doesn't understand the `apply` method signature (as it is only defined in subclasses' companion objects, not in the parent abstract class):

```
fields.collect {
    case field if providers.contains(field) => providers(field)(db).get(modelId)
                                                                ↑ won't compile
  }
```

Is there a way to make companion object's `apply` signature part of the abstract class? Or is there an another, better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the instances in your map would actually be the companion object, you could let the companion objects inherit from Function1 e.g.:

```
object LengthProvider extends ((DB) => LengthProvider) {
  def apply(v1: DB): LengthProvider = new LengthProvider(v1)
}

object WidthProvider extends ((DB) => WidthProvider) {
 def apply(v1: DB): WidthProvider = new WidthProvider(v1)
}

val providers: Map[String, ((DB) => FieldProvider)] = Map(
  "length" -> LengthProvider,
  "width"  -> WidthProvider
)
```

Comment: This worked well! Now I have a problem that in fact, `LengthProvider` requires an implicit argument as well. Can somehow forward it through this `apply` method in companion objects?